# Does the sf package in R use any online API?

Tags: r, api, r-sf

I am trying to understand if the sf package in R operates at the local (desktop) level or if it uses API to transmit information online. The documentation mentions the use of API to pull in algorithms but it is unclear to me what that involves.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would improve your question if you gave a more specific reference to the part of the documentation that mentions the use of an API (a quotation, or a link, or both ...)

Answer (score 2):

The package operates locally; once compiled it is perfectly capable of being run in firewalled contexts if that is your question.

Comment: That was my question. Thank you!